# fluid responsive <img> to css background

Tags: html, css, image

So i've made a fluid grid (with css) and so when I put an  with the grid classes, the images fluidly scale, wrap around each other. But I want to add hover effects to them, so I need to convert these  with classes into fluid css images.

But that's where the problem start. The css image isn't as fluid as it's html counterpart. How can I solve this? (To have the same fluid image with css as with html).

Thank you for your help! 
( I have searched other topics, but nont of them suit my needs).

Comment: Could you build a jsfiddle to show a semi-working example of your issue?

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bensji/dh6d3/ I think the images don't load, but you can see the css / html code. I would like to achieve the same fluidness (you can see the same code used on my webste http://www.bensji.byethost16.com)

Comment: I am just looking for the same resize-possibility my img element has.

Comment: I have found a semi-similar way with using:
'#image#
{
 background: url('../content/images/portfolio.jpg') center no-repeat;
 height: 222px;
 max-width:100%;
 margin-right: 0;
 background-size: contain;
}'
and the html putting in an ul (with every <li class="col col-sc1-12 col-sc2-6 col-sc3-4"> and then putting a <figure id="image#"></figure>

this almost does the same thing, but not yet till my full satisfaction. Can someone help me?